# SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'x'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I got this message when I execute my "little" program using NHibernate

```
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmployeeId', table 'NHibernateDemoDB.dbo.Employee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

My method is:

```
    private void SetEmployeeInfo(Employee employeeData)
    {
        employeeData.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        employeeData.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    }
```

and my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" namespace="NHibernateWinFormsApp" assembly="NHibernateWinFormsApp">

<class name="NHibernateWinFormsApp.Employee, NHibernateWinFormsApp" lazy="true">

    <id name="EmployeeId">

      <generator class="native"/>

    </id>

    <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName"/>

    <property name="LastName" column="LastName"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Does someone have an idea, please?
Thank you,

Comment: Column X requires a value, and you haven't passed a value. What is column X?

Comment: The message is pretty clear

Comment: I do have an idea! It wants a value for `EmployeeId` that isn't null. What do I win, a hammer?

Comment: The primary key of the table and it doesn't allow null values. (please, see my edit).

Comment: @user7879148 If it doesn't allow null values, try to imagine what other values you could give it. Is there a kind of value that isn't a `null` value? Maybe there is. Maybe that's the kind of value it wants. Give it a try, what can you lose?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I want to insert values in the database, but to increment the Id automatically.

Comment: If it's the primary key of the table and doesn't allow nulls and doesn't auto generate the value then my first guess is the values are in another table, or the table should be set to auto gen the values... is this a table you created? Check out the [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)  property

Comment: Is `SetEmployeeValue()` meant to *insert a new employee*, or update an existing one?

Comment: Your column X does not allow `NULL`s values , you have to pass a value to it, and that depends at the `datatype` of your column.

Comment: Some commentators here seem to have forgotten the "be nice" policy of Stack Overflow, while not even understanding parts of the question. The user is not issuing himself the query, and with his current setup, he cannot even specify a value for the not-nullable column. The only (partially) relevant comment here is currently [this one](/questions/44264547/sqlexception-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-x-column-does-not-allo/44265667#comment75537485_44264547) in my opinion.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, you win nothing, you have lost. The right solution for this question is not to specify a value: its settings will not let specifying a value. Maybe don't you know much about NHibernate for having answered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column definition is certainly wrong on your table in your database, lacking the `identity` specification.

Since you have mapped the id with generator `native`, which resolves to `identity` for sql-server, NHibernate tries to insert the entity without specifying a value for the Id `EmployeeId`, because it is supposed to be auto-generated on insert by the database.

And since it fails at that point, this means your table definition is invalid, it does not set `EmployeeId` as an `Identity` column, causing it to not be auto-generated on insert and thus lacking a value.

You have to fix your column definition on your table in the database.

Otherwise, choose another [generator strategy](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) for your id, one compatible with your database schema.

Comment: Yes, it was the auto-increment. That's it! Problem solved. Thank you all!

Answer (score -3):

The column doesn't allow null. As said on the message error.

You need to specify a value when getting a null. Use the ISNULL function.

Comment: This is a NHibernate mapped entity with a generator other than `assigned` for its id. NHibernate will not let the user specifies its value.

Comment: Humm, got it. Didn't know about that